# Delphi 2010 - IBX - UTF8 - dbmemo problem

Tags: delphi, utf-8, delphi-2010, blob, firebird

I am migrating an application from Delphi 6 - IBX - Firebird 1.5 that works great to Delphi 2010 - Firebird 2.1 - UTF8 database.

The problem is that if I use a `TDBMemo` to display data from a BLOB I get the following error:

> Debugger Exception Notification
>   Project accedo.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message
>   'Access violation at address 00686059 in module 'accedo.exe'. Read of address 000000EC'.

If I delete the memo component the program runs just fine.

The blob is a text BLOB (sub_type 1).

I know IBX doesn't support Firebird any more, but has anybody experienced 
problems using `TDBMemo` to retrieve and display UTF8 blob text from Firebird 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known problem about IBX and  UTF8 for Firebird.

I heard about a patch (not embarcadero) for this but I don't find it.

Other soltuion is to switch from IBX to FIBPlus, IBDac or UIB.

Comment: Thank you very much, it would be great if you remember where the solution is, I dont want to change the db controller at this time because it implies rewriting the whole app.
Any other recomendation besides FIBPlus, IBDac or UIB (these three are commercial productos, right?)

Comment: FIBPlus and IBDac are commercial product and there is some solution tools to migrate from IBX.
UIB is free, fast but you have to change many things.
For the patch, may be you can ask on firebird support list.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look at your recomendations. Regards AJ